How do I replace a LVDS display with another with different pinout?
I'm trying to retrofit this Alpine infotainment system in my old car (i905D-F)
It comes with an 9 inches display (C090EAN01.0) that does not fit in the original casing (CID z4 e85 and uses an old LCD 6.4 inches display).
I've managed to find an 8 inches display (C080EAN01.0) that fit with some 3D printed parts and it works as a drop-in replacement with the original PCB from the Alpine system, it's the same pinout as the 9" display.
If you want to take a look at the project here.
BUT, I think it does not look right with the interior of the car and I'm trying to fit a smaller display, ideally 7 inches.
I've got this 7 inches display C070EAN03.0, different pinout, but similar specs
720P
LVDS 1 channel, 8 bits
I tried matching the pins from the board to the display, but I get no output on the display, and also no backlight, am I missing something?
Can it be related to the different clock use by the LVDS signal?
EDIT:
The board uses a chip that only output 720p it seems
max9282a.
For the pinouts of the display, it can be found in the datasheets of the displays.
Picture below is from the Alpine system board that drives the display, the FPC connectors 40 pins goes from right to left.
EDIT_2:
The backlight is managed by a second FPC 10 pins connector on the board, I tried inverting the polarity from the display to the board, and still no backlight
Also, what's the difference between the VDD and VDDA on the 9 inches panel ? The 7 inche panel only need a single power source, VDD


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Here is my two cents.
There are two LVDS standards in market. But since yours are 8 bits, they should be fine. There are two directions you can check for TFT screen. The screens' voltages and backlights voltages. They may be different.
